# How many hamburgers can be ordered, if there can be eight toppings?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A fast food restaurant offers customer a choice of eight toppings that can be added to a hamburger. How many different hamburgers can be ordered?

Attempt: I don't know if this is correct 8!? I think there is no sufficient information. Can anyone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: "I think there is no sufficient information"...what more information do you think you need? If you figure this out, you may be able to at least give an answer of the kind "if we allow this, then x, if we do not allow it, then y"...

Comment: What happens if you are vegetarian? Can you order it without the meat?

Comment: This question is not worded clearly thus some assumptions need to be made about it.  You didn't ask how many hamburger combinations are possible from the $8$ available toppings, you asked how many different hamburgers can be ordered.  What if someone doesn't know what toppings are available and orders an unavailable topping?  That counts as a order but it is not one of the $8$ available toppings.  For example, they order pickles but those are not available.  Also how do we know if the $8$ toppings are constant or change over time?  You didn't state that either. What do you mean by different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either have a topping on your hamburger, or you can not have a topping on your hamburger. Suppose there is only one topping, ketchup: Then you have two possible hamburgers, one with ketchup and one without. Suppose you now also have mustard. Then you have four possible burgers: no ketchup & no mustard, ketchup & no mustard, no ketchup & mustards, ketchup & mustard.

In general, with $n$ toppings, you have $2 \times 2 \times \cdots \times 2 = 2^n$ possible toppings. (Do you understand why?) If $n=8$, then...

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Thank you for explaining

Comment: I think he meant $2^n$ possible topping combinations, not toppings.

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter how the topping are ordered? Put differently: is a hamburger equipped with mustard and secondly (on top of the mustard) ketchup different than one equipped with ketchup and secondly (on top of the ketchup) mustard? If so then:

$k$ of the $8$ toppings  take care of $k!$ possible hamburgers. You come to a total of:$$
\binom80\times0!+\binom81\times1!+\cdots+\binom88\times8!$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume a customer can order a burger with all eight toppings. The order of the toppings likely does not matter, or in a real-world scenario it's specified by the restaurant (i.e. cheese is adjacent to the patty and ketchup is spread on the bun). Therefore, it uses combinations $\binom{n}{r}$, not permutations.

A zero topping burger has $\binom{8}{0}$ possibilities, or 1 possible burger.
A one topping burger has $\binom{8}{1}$ possibilities, or 8 possible burgers.
A two topping burger has $\binom{8}{2}$ possibilities, or 28 possible burgers.
A three topping burger has $\binom{8}{3}$ possibilities, or 56 possible burgers.
A four topping burger has $\binom{8}{4}$ possibilities, or 70 possible burgers.
A five topping burger has $\binom{8}{5}$ possibilities, or 56 possible burgers.
A six topping burger has $\binom{8}{6}$ possibilities, or 28 possible burgers.
A seven topping burger has $\binom{8}{7}$ possibilities, or 8 possible burgers.
An eight topping burger has $\binom{8}{8}$ possibilities, or 1 possible burger.
The sum is 256 possible burgers.